# Beanstalk enviorment overrieds the Lauch Template setting in Auto Scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using an Beanstalk service and want each of the t2.micro instances to automatically have t2.unlimited credit. How can that be possible? Is there any .ebextensions config command that I can follow?

After some R&D,  I have now created a Launch Template and have updated the Auto Scaling Groups to use that Launch Template (this launch template enables t2.unlimited on the t2.micro instances when they are launched by the scaling groups). However, when I update the configuration of Beanstalk Environment from AWS UI console, it automatically removes the Launch Template from the Auto Scaling Groups and puts back the original Launch Configuration instead. Why is so? And how can I fix it so that updating environment doesn't remove the launch template from the scaling groups? FYI, when I edit the Auto Scaling group and add new instances from there, it seems to be working fine perfectly and new launched instances already have t2.unilmited enabled. Also, Beanstalk doesn't seem to be deploying the environment on the instances added by the Autoscaling group's Launch Template. I think the issue might be in CludFormation stack. I can see that Cloudformation stack contains a resource called "LauchConfiguration" which I am wanting to change to Launch Template that I created. But that doesn't seem to be possible? So can anyone please help me achieve my goal based on the finding I have shared? Thank you!

Comment: This is an issue for serverfault. I actually created one today: https://serverfault.com/questions/986397/how-to-change-elastic-beanstalk-launch-configuration-to-launch-template